# Registering facebook app without including sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since iOS has built in Facebook sharing (via UIActivityViewController), I'm easily able to post without including the FB SDK. However, when I post to my timeline, I want it to say "via AppName". Do I have to add the sdk to my app or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to [create a Facebook App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and use the [iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios).